# Creating "onload" functionality in Dynamic HTML

Tags: jquery, dhtml

Using jquery ajax I populate contents of a div with HTML.

This new HTML data has javascript code (this part works correctly). However this javascript also has

```
$(document).load(function() { ... });
```

This part does not work since document is already loaded!

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing fancy is actually needed. It seems that dynamically loaded javascript is executed after the dynamic content is parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's always going to be loaded via AJAX? If so, why not just remove the `$(document).load()` altogether?

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're suggesting

Comment: I'm asking you why you're putting your JavaScript inside a `$(document).load()` callback when you're loading that content from the server *after the page loads*.

Comment: The "page" loads first. Then the page loads new content and shoves it in the div. I'd like the new content to specify a function that needs to be executed when the new content is loaded